# avisynth "transparent" overlaying audio

Tags: audio, avisynth

How overlay audio onto other audio? 
I want to make a FadeIO(..) feature for audio channels of clips in avisynth.
I have this script

```
video = DirectShowSource("Z:\video\vvv.mp4", fps=fps_count, audio=true, convertfps=true).AssumeFPS(fps_count, 1).ConvertToYV12()
audio = BlankClip(audio_rate=audio_sample_rate, channels=2, length = logo_timeout).ResampleAudio(audio_sample_rate)

blank = BlankClip(logo_timeout, res_width, res_height, pixel_type = "RGB32", fps = fps_count).ConvertToYV12()
blank = Overlay(blank, blank_logo, mode = "blend", x = 0, y = 0)
blank = AudioDub(blank, blank_logo).AssumeFPS(fps_count, 1)
```

And smooth overlaying of parts of videos is like this:

```
blank.Trim(0 * fps_count, transparent_overlay_latency * fps_count).Overlay(video.Trim(0 * fps_count, transparent_overlay_latency * fps_count), mode="blend", mask=logo.showalpha(), x = 0, y = 0)
```

But this works only for videos. The audio starts when second clip (video.Trim()) is already faded In. I want the sound of this video "grows up" , when the clip appears.

Comment: It's hard to produce anything from the example script, since it's missing a lot of key variables, but I'd recommend using http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Dissolve, it allows for gradual transition between two clips, both in terms of video and audio.

Comment: @Seedmanc, thank you very much! :) It is exactly what I need!) 
This is really much simplier method))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the @SeedManc said in commentary under question:

> avisynth.nl/index.php/Dissolve, it allows for gradual transition between two clips, both in terms of video and audio.

This method is very simple and is the answer for my question